# Duplicate class error while building project android

Tags: android, gradle

I am building my project and getting the following errors of duplicate class

```
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback found in modules browser-1.4.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0) and customtabs-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback$Stub found in modules browser-1.4.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0) and customtabs-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback$Stub$Proxy found in modules browser-1.4.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0) and customtabs-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsService found in modules browser-1.4.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0) and customtabs-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsService$Stub found in modules browser-1.4.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0) and customtabs-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsService$Stub$Proxy found in modules browser-1.4.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0) and customtabs-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.IPostMessageService found in modules browser-1.4.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0) and customtabs-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.IPostMessageService$Stub found in modules browser-1.4.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0) and customtabs-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.IPostMessageService$Stub$Proxy found in modules browser-1.4.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0) and customtabs-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.7.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.7.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.7.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
```

These are my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation files('libs/release.aar')
implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.1"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:2.17.1"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was to able to solve by adding  `android.enableJetifier=true` in `gradle.properties` file

Comment: was it everything you did ? I have now
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.browser.browser-1.4.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.browser.browser-1.4.0:) instead of previous error

Comment: @RomainBitard for you I think the `exclude` tag will work out on your dependency.
Just `exclude browser` from your `customtab` dependency

Comment: Didn't know about that, I'll try that someday if I have the same problem ! (I use unity so the build is supposed to be handled by the framework)